# Firebase on OS X persistent file location?

Tags: objective-c, macos, firebase

I enabled persistence on my Mac app, but even though I've reset the data on Firebase server and there is now an internet connection, the Mac app isn't updating with the server data neither is the server updating with the Mac data...

Aside from the fact that this is weird and I'd expect data to sync one way or the other, where is the local offline file stored so I can delete it?

Answer (score 0):

No replies so answering my own question.

Managed to track down the local files to this location

```
~/.firebase/default/<yourfirebaseurl>_appname
```